# How can parse these file pattern in php?

Tags: php, parsing, file-read

I have some .ini file to read by PHP.
Then, the styles of file contents are as follows;

```
[title1]
delete_date = 0101,0211,1115

[title2]
setting_day_name = aaa, bbb
setting_day = 0811, 1201

[title3]
company = c1,c2,c3
```

I want some arrays with each sessions(title1, title2, title3) like this;

```
title1 = array(0101,0211,1115);
title2 = array({'setting_day_name' => aaa, 'setting_day' => '0811'}, 
{setting_day_name: bbb, setting_day: 1201});
title3 = array(c1,c2,c3);
```

I think how to divide sessions and items in each session is important.
How can I pass this file?

Comment: Start with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use the `parse_ini_file` function of PHP (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), available since PHP 4.

In your case:

```php
$data = parse_ini_file("my_file.ini", true); // true to decode sections

/*
Result:
$data === [
  'title1' => [
    'delete_date' => '0101,0211,1115'
    ...
*/
```